# Efficient GC-assisted cleanup of LARGE native resources

Tags: java, garbage-collection, java-native-interface

I'm currently attempting to write a tensor-processing/deep learning library in Java similar to PyTorch or Tensorflow.

Tensors reference MemoryHandles, which hold the native memory needed for the tensor data.
During training, tensor instances are created rapidly, but never the less, the JVM heap itself stays about 100Mb-200Mb and thus the garbage collector is never prompted to garbage collect.
This results in the memory footprint of the application exploding and consuming upwards of 16GB of RAM, due to how much native memory is needed to store the tensor data.

The memory handles themselves are allocated via a cental MemoryManager, which creates PhantomReferences to the handed out handles, and after the object is garbage collected, the associated native memory is correctly freed.

## What makes this problem hard

### Why is the GC not smart enough to instantly clean these tensors?

Operations such as `.matmul()`, `.plus()` etc. are not immediately executed, but rather recorded into a `Graph`, where nodes represent either variables or operations. This graph is necessary for backpropagation and thus creating it is not optional.
This creates a rather complicated reference structure that is hard to unravel for a GC.

## Attempted solutions

I have attempted various less then ideal ways to fix this problem:

### Insanely small JVM heap size

`-Xmx100M`

By forcing the Garbage collector to work with insanely low heap sizes, the garbage collector keeps the native memory footprint bearable.
This introduces very little slow down to the training loop in the cases I have evaluated and would be bearable, if finding out that ideal MB to make the GC do what you want wasn't so painful. Also, if the memory usage of your application isn't more or less constant, this approach also bursts into flames.

### Periodic full gc

Running a full gc for every X Mb of natively allocated memory.
This introduces abysmal slow down to the training loop in the cases I have evaluated.
This is the only "in-application" fix that I can think of, meaning, that the user is not forced to use weird jvm args when running their program.
While `-XX:+UseZGC` and `-XX:+ExplicitGCInvokesConcurrent` show some improvement, the situation remains rather bad.

Both these solutions do in fact keep the memory footprint of the application at bay, which goes to show that IF the GC catches all the un-referenced MemoryHandles, everything is freed correctly.

## Thus my question:

When Jvm applications experience high allocation rates, the GC usually kicks in hard.
Now the problem here is that we have *effectively* high allocation rates, but that is not at all reflected in the JVM heap. If you put yourself into the shoes of the Garbage Collector, the least that you suspect is that freeing a java object solely consisting of an 8 byte long is where you should place your efforts.
If however it was possible to hint the GC to try harder to free objects of the `MemoryHandle` type, I suspect these problems would largely disappear. So my question would be: Is this possible?
I wouldn't mind writing hacky native code, if necessary.

Another idea would be to use some jvm argument to make the full GC less aggressive, more in line with the slight slowdown that I experienced with `-Xmx100m` .

If this is in fact not possible, are there alternative solutions to sovling this problem?
Surely I can't be the first person to attempt to write a Java library with large native resources.

Comment: Not really a problem of GC not being smart, it has no desire to clean up if there's a lot of JVM space. Would it be possible to reuse the native memory / memory handles rather than relying on GC to clean them? I.e. manual object pool where you can return handles to once no longer in use

Comment: Well, if I had a nice spot where I could declare a memory handle as no longer in use, pooling wouldn't even be necessary because then I could just call .free()

The problem is that I rely on the garbage collector to determine whether they are still in use or not quite literally by the nature of the API that I am exposing.

There is a place in the code where I can be 60% sure that the tensor is no longer in use. The GraphRecorder drops the history of how tensors of previous training iterations came to be, but that only replaces operation nodes with constant variables inside the graph.

Comment: Can you wrap your MemoryHandles and add a reference count?

Comment: MemoryHandles basically always have an immediate reference count of 1, as they are parent to the tensor object. Adding a reference count to the tensor is not really possible. If you look at the API surface of eg. PyTorch or Tensorflow, the tensor objects are created by the user, and handled in what ever way they please. If the user decides to keep a random tensor from iteration 13 alive in a list and shoots it back into my face at iteration 3475, you have to be ready for that.

Comment: That's not to say that this is the norm, but in the default case, when references "flow" cleanly, where basically 95% of tensors die at the end of the iteration, it's got to be possible to SOMEHOW not blow your RAM xD

Comment: a) with soft references you can tune `XX:SoftRefLRUPolicyMSPerMB` to cleanup softly references objects faster b) using the native memory allocated by `ByteBuffer.allocateDirect()` might allow you to tune the GC for native space via `XX:MaxDirectMemorySize` c) wouldn't but manually calling `System.gc()` d) require the user of your library to free / pool / .. handles, if you make the api you also make the rules. Libraries that can't rely on GC do that (e.g. https://netty.io/4.0/api/io/netty/util/ReferenceCounted.html or https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap#recycle() )

Comment: a) Unfortunately the MemoryHandle must be strongly referenced by the Tensor, otherwise the contents of a tensor that might still be in use could just dissapear.
b) Even if ByteBuffer.allocateDirect() could get the garbage collector to respond to native memory growth, this really doesn't help much in the GPU backend, where memory is allocated on the GPU via cuMemAlloc.

Comment: c) Currently experimenting with an interval where every x mb System.gc() is invoked on an aysnc thread, and every x * 10 mb System.gc() is invoked in the same thread.
Same thread gc block execution for about 10 ms, but perform better.
Surprisingly this actually works pretty well. If I don't find a better solution, this might just be the hack I'm going to stick with...

Comment: In addition, I might just create a system where you have to detach tensors from the graph, before you can just do whatever you want with them. If you find yourself holding on to a tensor attached to a graph that has been deleted, you will get a giant exception if you try to do anything with it.
That detached tensor will be a copy of the original node. Now... This is not even close to what detaching from the graph means in PyTorch, but... I'm afraid I have to redefine this terminology... I'm starting to understand why Python is so ideal for machine learning. A reference count sure is handy

Comment: Assuming HotSpot/OpenJDK, even the internal handling of `ByteBuffer.allocateDirect()` is not better than calling `System.gc()` when suspecting that the native memory is low due to reclaimable direct buffers. This suggests that there is no better solution, as otherwise, direct buffers would use it. Note that dealing with soft references wouldn’t solve anything, as those policies apply *after* the GC detected reclaimable soft references. They don’t affect when the GC will run.

Comment: I think you are stumbling across the exact reason `finalize` was a bad idea and is being removed from the language: you have no guarantee when the finalizer will be run. Not that that helps you any further of course..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that I have now figured out a solution that works as good as it can.

## The problem

If you face a similar issue you probably have code that fits some of these criterias:

1. A high allocation rate of small objects, which hold large native resources
2. Objects referencing each other in complicated ways that is hard for the GC to untangle
3. No place in the code where you can safely determine that the resources are no longer in use

## Requirements for a potential solution

Your requirements probably are:

1. Don't bottleneck the loop that allocates the native handles
2. Nearly instantanious cleanup after the native handle becomes unreferenced

### The tradeoff

It turns out you cannot accomplish both these requirements at once.
You unfortunately have to choose between one or the other.
If you don't want to bottleneck the loop that allocates these native handles at a high rate, you need to trade RAM to do that.
If you want instantatious cleanup after the native handle becomes unreferenced,
you have to sacrifice the execution speed of the code that allocates the native handles.

## The (hacky) solution

Create a mechanism such that you can asynchronously request a full GC to be performed.

```java
    private final AtomicBoolean shouldRunGC = new AtomicBoolean(false);

    private final Thread gcThread = new Thread(() -> {
        while (true) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(10);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            if (shouldRunGC.getAndSet(false)) {
                System.gc();
            }
        }
    }, "GC-Invoker-Thread");

    {
        gcThread.setDaemon(true);
        gcThread.start();
    }
```

Ideally, you have a region of code that is loosely associated with cleanup of these handle objects. It doesn't have to mean that these objects can be safely disposed at this point in time, it just has to mean that the object is >probably< safe to delete. This callsite merely serves a statistical metric to determine the best intervall in which to trigger the Garbage Collection.
You should also know the size of your native resource, or alternatively an estimate of how bad it would be to keep a given object arround.

Alternatively you could also place this at the point of the allocation of your native handles, but note that the effectiveness of the statistical metric that you collect is less effective.

This is an example of such a method in my tensor processing library Sci-Core:

```java
    /**
     * Drops the history of how this tensor was computed.
     * This is useful e.g. when the tensor was changed by the optimizer
     * and thus backpropagation back into the last training step (wtf) would be brain-dead.
     * Thus, we no longer need to keep a record of how the tensor was computed.
     * Executes all operations to compute the value of the specified tensor contained in the graph, if it is not already computed.
     * @param tensor the tensor to drop the computation history for
     */
    public void dropHistory(ITensor tensor) {
      // for all nodes now dropped from the graph
      ...
          nBytesDeletedSinceLastAsyncGC += value.getNumBytes();
          nBytesDeletedSinceLastOnSameThreadGC += value.getNumBytes();
      ...

       if (nBytesDeletedSinceLastAsyncGC > 100_000_000) { // 100 Mb
           shouldRunGC.set(true);
           nBytesDeletedSinceLastAsyncGC = 0;
       }
       if (nBytesDeletedSinceLastOnSameThreadGC > 2_000_000_000) { // 2 GB
           System.gc();
           nBytesDeletedSinceLastOnSameThreadGC = 0;
       }
    }
```

To fight against bottlenecking your allocation loop, you can use the following JVM arguments:

```
-XX:+UseZGC -XX:+ExplicitGCInvokesConcurrent -XX:MaxGCPauseMillis=1
```

## Why would this work?

Triggering regular garbage collection seems to make the garbage collector interested in cleaning the very small handle objects (among basically every other object that you create in your application. You still don't have "prioritization" for your handles, they just happen to also be garbage collected. If your application in addition to the native handle objects also allocates a significant amount of other small objects, the effectiveness of this technique will be significantly reduced.

Note however, that triggering the Garbage collector is expensive and thus the maximum value for `nBytesDeletedSinceLastAsyncGC` and `nBytesDeletedSinceLastOnSameThreadGC` must be carefully chosen.
Running the garbage collector asynchronously is less expensive, as it will not bottleneck your allocation loop very much but also less effective than calling the garbage collector on the same thread the objects are allocated. So, doing both in carefully chosen intervals can probably get you a good compromise between execution speed of your allocation loop and memory footprint.